# Keycloak conditional "either A or B" flow

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-flows

so what's the best way to configure an "either A or B" conditional flow in Keycloak, based on a user attribute?
So far I go with the user attribute condition and then a copy with the condition negated:

```
- Flow (conditional)
  - Condition - user attribute ATTR=X (required)
  - Execution A (required)
- Flow (conditional)
  - Condition - user attribute ATTR=X Negate=On (required)
  - Execution B (required)
```

But that doesn't seem right to me. It kinda works, but I get strange effects e.g. when using the back button during login and sometimes the wron condition triggers.
In one specific example the Execution A would be a redirect to an external SAML Identity Provider, while B would be a password form.